# Copy folder with it's content in gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a folder `node_modules` which contains `@bower_components` folder, `jquery-powertip` folder and other folders.

Using a gulp task I want to copy the content of the `@bower_components` folder and the `jquery-powertip` folder with it's content to a destination folder.

The problem I'm facing is copying the `jquery-powertip` folder with it's content.

I tried as following :

```
gulp.task('move-dependencies', function () {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/@bower_components/**', 'node_modules/jquery-powertip'])
               .pipe( gulp.dest(src + '/bower_components') );
});
```

But this will only copy the `jquery-powertip` folder without it's content.

I tried this too :

```
gulp.task('move-dependencies', function () {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/@bower_components/**', 'node_modules/jquery-powertip/**'])
               .pipe( gulp.dest(src + '/bower_components') );
});
```

But this will copy the content of the `jquery-powertip` folder to the target folder destination (I'm not getting the "jquery-powertip" folder in target, just its contents)

So how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
gulp.task('move-dependencies', function () {
    var task1 = gulp.src(['node_modules/@bower_components/**'])
                .pipe( gulp.dest(src + '/bower_components') );
    var task2 = gulp.src(['node_modules/jquery-powertip/**'])
                .pipe( gulp.dest(src + '/bower_components/jquery-powertip') );
    return [ task1, task2 ]; // or merge(task1, task2);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work it throws some kind of exception that I can't see because I'm using the `frontend-maven-plugin` to run gulp tasks.

Comment: can you create a seperate task like `move-dependencies-2` etc?

Comment: Nevermind, I used the merge plugin and instead of returning an array or the both tasks, I did this : `return merge(task1, task2)`.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll fix that for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone revisits such a problem. It worked for me to put an asterisks infront of the folder you want to keep (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1358#issuecomment-563448694)

```
// will copy the assets folder and its sub directories + files to the destination
return gulp.src('assets*/**/*')

// will only copy the sub directories + files of the assets folder to the destination
return gulp.src('assets/**/*')
```